# update statement with random string generator c#

Tags: c#, sql, oracle

I am trying to update user passwords by using a random generator. The update statement itself is a fairly simple statement but has case statements so depending on the user, they will get this special password.

My code works to generate the random value and updates the records, however, it updates ALL records with the SAME password instead of generating a NEW set of random values for each record that needs to be updated (there will be an unknown amount of passwords updated/created at any given time).

If I need a loop, how can I integrate the loop with the SQL statement?

Here is a ROUGH sample of the code:

```
string colors[] = {"green", "blue", "yellow", "black"};
random r = new Random();
int index= r.Next(0, colors.Length);
string color =colors[index].ToString();

query = "update table set password = '" + r.color + '";
```

What am I missing??

Comment: Is your goal to update *all* the passwords in the table in one go with random values?  Or do you want to only update a certain list of users?

Comment: @sstan it's in the question, `it updates ALL records with the SAME password instead of generating a NEW set of random values for each record `

Comment: @Sherlock: That states what happens, not her intention.

Comment: There also tons of questions on how to update single record in DB, how to deal with passwords in SQL, how to properly generate random numbers,... You may want to show real [MCVE] instead of rough sample which does not show any indication on how you plan to update single record.

Answer (score 2):

You are not being very clear on how you would deal with password updates on a per user basis.  The way your code is setup now, you are updating the whole table in one go without any loop.  I don't think you should be surprised at all that it doesn't work.

If you are in fact interested in randomly updating *all* the passwords in the table with one of the 4 colors, I would do that with a single `update` statement instead of a loop:

```sql
update tbl
   set pwd = case abs(mod(dbms_random.random, 4))
               when 0 then 'green'
               when 1 then 'blue'
               when 2 then 'yellow'
               when 3 then 'black'
             end
```

Comment: I wont prefer this, since it is hard to maintain, difficult to add more colors

Comment: @un-lucky: I don't see how this is any harder to maintain than what OP currently has, and it will be way faster than any solution that requires executing multiple `update` statements in a loop. But thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Well its fine ,i was mistaken. Better solution

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a `where` condition in the update query to update some specific records(let it be the `username`). Then Saving password as plain text will not be a good option, So I suggest you to use some encryption. another tip for you is You have to declare the random variable as global .

The complete things can be achieved through the following code:

```
Random r = New Random(); // this will be global
String colors[] = {"green", "blue", "yellow", "black"};    
int index = r.Next(0, colors.Length);
String colorPassword = colors[index].ToString(); // This will be the password
// Now encrypt the password 
byte[] byteData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(colorPassword);
byteData = new System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256Managed().ComputeHash(byteData );
String hashedPassword = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(byteData );

query = "update table set password = '" + hashedPassword + "' where username='" + your_username + "'";
// Here you can execute the query
```